# How to use @XmlMixed , @XmlElement and @XmlValue all together?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have already seen some of the discussions related to this but cannot apply this in following scenario . I am trying to `unmarshall an xml using jaxb`.
Following is the hierarchy of all my classes .

```
 @XmlRootElement(name="entry")
 class Entry extedns Base{

     @XmlElement
     private String id;
     @XmlElement
     private String name;
     @XmlElementRef
     @XmlMixed
     private Begin begin;
     @XmlElementRef
     @XmlMixed
     private End end;
     @XmlElementRef
     private List<Link> links;


//Getter setters
}



@XmlRootElement(name="begin",namespace = "something")
    public class Begin extends AnotherBase{
            @XmlValue
            private Float mFloat;
            //Getter Setters
    }

@XmlRootElement(name="end",namespace = "something")
public class End  extends AnotherBase{
        @XmlValue
        private Float mFloat;
        //Getter Setters
}


@XmlRootElement(name="link",namespace = "something")
public class Link extends Base{
        private String attname;
        private String attValue;
        //Getter Setters
}
```

I want an xml like following :

```
<entry>
    <id>...</id>
    <name>...</name>
    <begin>1.23344</begin>
    <end>5.0</end>
    <link>
        <link>......</link>
        <link>......</link>
    </link>
</entry>
```

As you can that ,

1. The Entry class has both 2 `@XmlElement` annotated variable and 2 `@XmlElementRef` annoted Variable (Begin,End)  .
2. Both Begin and End class has `@Xmlvalue` annotated variable .
3. Both Begin and End class have derived from some other class
4. The Link class might have Variables of type attributes and elements.

I failed to use `@XmlMixed` , as you can see i put `@XmlMixed` at the top of the variable declaration in Entry class .

The result of this marshalling is

```
@XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.Float Begin.mFloat
        at Begin
        at private Begin Entry.begin

If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.
 this problem is related to the following location:
    at private java.lang.Float Begin.mFloat
    at Begin
```

Comment: first of all `@XMLValue` is used with `@XMLAttribute`

Comment: So I cannot expect to see the xml like i mentioned in the question ? If I use @XmlAttribute instead of @XmlElementRef then my xml will look something like `<entry begin="123.455" end="5.0">...</entry>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate `AnotherBase` with `@XmlTransient` to remove it as a mapped super class.  If there are any get/set method pairs on `AnotherBase` that are not mapped with `@XmlAttribute` then you will need to annotate them with `@XmlTransient`.

You don't need the `@XmlMixed` annotations on the `begin` and `end` properties.

I notice you are annotating the fields (instance variables).  When you do this you should specify the following on your class @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`

Comment: I have added `@XmlTransient` in my `AnotherBase` now the exception `@XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class.` is gone , But I get another exception `If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.` But this time it is  related to a  Getter method of variable `List<MyXml>` of `AnotherBase`. Why am I getting this exception when i have annotated the `AnotherBase` as `@XmlTransient`

Comment: The problem is not related to Another Base , I have to use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)`